# How to redirect to particular page when provided login credentials

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

While using spring security I am providing a particular page with ROLE_ANONYMOUS user.

```
<intercept-url pattern="/runApp*"
        access="hasAnyRole('User', 'Admin','ROLE_ANONYMOUS')" />
```

There are many other intercept urls in the same http tag of spring security. This is my spring security code:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
<intercept-url pattern='/welcome*' access="hasAnyRole('User', 'Admin')" />
<intercept-url pattern="/runApp*" access="hasAnyRole('User', 'Admin','ROLE_ANONYMOUS')" />
<form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?login_error=true" default-target-url="/welcome" />
<logout logout-success-url="/login" invalidate-session="true" />
```

When user logins for the first time it redirects to welcome page. But when he wants to access runApp page he has to provide his credentials in the login page. But when he provides login credential it redirects to welcome page. Whereas I want it to redirect to particular runApp page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to a workaround. Not the best solution, but, if someone has something better to show, I'm all ears. When redirecting to login page for the credentials i am saving the data in the session. And when the registered user logins it goes to the controller where i get the data from the session and redirect it to the desired page.
Thanks for your support... :)

Answer (score 0):

There is another attribute in `form-login` element named `always-use-default-target` which defines redirect rule after login. If value of this attribute set to `false`, then user will be redirected to `default-target-url` only after requesting login page directly.

Comment: no luck still the same its again redirecting it to welcome page.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/myproject/runApp?data=12 this the link which can accessed by anonymous user. when he pastes in the browser he is redirected to login page for his credentials following is the code in the controller.  Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
     .getAuthentication();
   if ((auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
    return "login";
   } so when he logins with proper credential he will be redirected to the particular page.

Comment: If this link must be unsecured put it in another `http` element with disabled security.
    
    <http pattern="/runApp*" security="none" />

Comment: In the link data=12 suggest different info for particular user. So the page is depended upon the field 'data'. Some registered user wants there data to be viewed by other registered users only. So when the registered user pastes this link in the browser he is directed to login page. And when he logins it should be redirected to the particular page. But in my case its by default going to welcome page.